# Congratulations, Arduino SE is graduating!

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

It's been a long road (over 1200 days, and that's just counting this most recent attempt at building an Arduino community), but I have good news:

**Arduino Stack Exchange is graduating!**

Congratulations to all who participated, especially the moderators and regular users who gave so much of their time and effort. Reaching "mature community" status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

After you graduate, there will be some changes around here. Graduation works in two phases. The first phase starts now, and includes the following benefits:

- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name.
- You will become eligible for question migration paths to/from the rest of the network.
- You will be able to participate in the next round of community ads. There'll be a separate post here on meta soon about setting those up; if you don't know what community ads are, check out [an example of how they'll work](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9463/community-promotion-ads-2016) over on Code Golf SE.
- You get to enter the line for a community moderator election. Based on the number of other sites waiting, your election should happen in August.

Later, the site will still receive a full custom design from one of our staff designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, so instead of making you wait to receive all the parts of graduation at once, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. We think we've hammered out most of the bugs in the process, but there are still likely to be some left. If you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This community has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps a lot of people, including many who never type a word of their own on the site. Congratulations again on all you've accomplished!

Comment: :-) Great Job, guys!

Comment: About time! Thanks to all who made possible!!

Comment: Switch is flipped, y'all are full on graduated now.

Comment: Indeed! Congrats from the Electrical Engineering SE :) I was wondering why it took so long lol. Maybe question migration will be easier for the both of us ;)