# Is dark mode coming for Arduino SE?

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow has a setting in the preferences for Light/Dark mode for quite some time now.
I would like to also have a dark mode in Arduino SE.

I don't know how such things are handled in the Stack Exchange environment. Is it planned to provide this feature on Arduino SE? If not, why? Is there some kind of hindrance for this to come to Arduino SE?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359739/plans-for-dark-mode-for-all-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: Mhh, that sounds like "not in the next 5 to 10 years". Sad thing. Should I delete this question, since already answered on meta SE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by [the link that Juraj posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359739/plans-for-dark-mode-for-all-stack-exchange-sites) it would be a massive effort to redesign the multiple Stack Exchange sites. They would have carefully chosen palettes of colours in the existing design, and the whole thing would have to be reworked to make a dark theme.

You will notice that [this site graduated](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/congratulations-arduino-se-is-graduating) in 2017, and in that post they said:

> Later, the site will still receive a full custom design from one of our staff designers ...

Five years later, this site got its custom design. So even if Stack Exchange agreed to rework each site to have a dark theme, you might be waiting a *long* time for it to actually happen. There are around 180 sites they would have to work on.